# Edit R data frame to plot multiple lines on the same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data in the given format:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6gFM.png)
so it is categories on the far left (row names), and months are on the top (column names)

And I need to create a plot with a line for each Group.1 category on the same plot, which will have x axis of month and y axis as the corresponding value.  Initially I was thinking of creating a separate data frame for each category with month and value as columns, but it seems there should be a better way.  Any ideas?

I tried transposing the data frame, which would allow me to get the month and values correctly, but I would not know what category they would be for plotting the lines.

Comment: The tidyr package has a function called `pivot_longer()` which sounds applicable to your problem (https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html). If you check out the examples there, I believe you will be able to solve your issue. If you can't solve it yourself, please edit your question to include some example data and the code you've tried (i.e. a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: Greetings! Rather than a screenshot of your data, usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg